# updating a dropdown boxes contents when clicking a checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to work out the best way to get this to work.  What i am trying to do is as follows:

i have a page which 10 checkboxes on it.  I want to have a dynamic drop down which is populated with a list of server names when a checkbox is clicked

Example:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="site4" name="list[]" type="checkbox" value="BERT">
        <label id="site4l">BERT</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="site5" name="list[]" type="checkbox" value="BOB">
        <label id="site5l">BOB</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would also have on the other side of the page a select dropdown which i want to be populated when a checkbox is checked, i would also like the values to be removed from the select dropdown if the checkbox has been unchecked.

I thought about something like this

setting a hash in javascript

```
serverList["BERT"] = ["server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5"];
serverList["BOB"] = ["server8", "server9", "server10", "server11"];
```

and then i am a little stuck on how i can build the list and display.  I have seen a few jquery pluggins which group items in a checkbox which look good.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks Mithandra

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code to work on? To just work out of the blue is a bit hard.

In general: What you are looking for is the `change` event (http://api.jquery.com/change/).
I personally would add a change event to all the checkboxes and if unchecked just remove (http://api.jquery.com/remove/) all coresponding entries, if checked then just append them (http://api.jquery.com/append/) to your dropdown.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

I guess being from a perl background what i was looking to do is say i have various checkboxs with the different names example of one might be BOB

i would have some sort of java array like
fields[BOB] = [ array of servers ]

when i checked the box it would then go and look up the list of servers using the key of BOB and then populate the dropdown box with the list of servers.

The way I was thinking of doing this is to build some sort of hash within java from which a select dropdown could be produced. so in the event that the user unchecked a box that they had already checked the key and subsequent values would be removed from the hash.

i am not really sure on how to achieve this within Java as i only dabble with it.